# Error while adding username to my rails web app(devise gem)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a certain error bugging my head during adding username in my rails web app.

I did what it says in link: https://rubyonrailshelp.wordpress.com/2014/01/07/adding-a-username-to-the-user-admin-model/

There seems a error in browser like:

```
NoMethodError in Devise::RegistrationsController#edit 

undefined method `for' for #<Devise::ParameterSanitizer:0xa8342f0>

 def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me) }
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_in) { |u| u.permit(:username, :email, :password, :remember_me) }
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) {|u| u.permit(:username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password)} #for account update
```

What making the error in ***application_controller.rb***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

`devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:name])`

And as [@J.D.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4554116/j-d) mentioned, use `before_action` rather than `before_filter`.